# update the defaultValue on re

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here in the input box, I am passing an initial value by useState hook. Now suppose I type in the input field and re-render the component by clicking the 'change' button, it still shows the typed input value.
 But I want to have the initial value when the component re-renders. How to do that?

```
import React , { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App({val}) {
 const [value, setValue] = useState(val);
 const [x, setX] = useState(100);

const handleChange = (e) => {
 console.log(e.target.value)
 setValue(e.target.value)
} 

const handleClick = () => {
 console.log('l')
 setX(10)
}

useEffect(() => {
console.log('ef')
}, [x])
return (
<div className="App">
  <input 
    name="box"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  {x}
  <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Change</button>
</div>
```

);
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can just reset your value state on that button click i.e.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setValue(val);
  setX(10)
}
```